# Unable to include static library containing QObject class into Cascades project

Tags: qt, blackberry-10, qmake, blackberry-cascades, moc

I work on the new BB10 platform based on Qt.

I have one static library project which defines a `QObject` class (basically the class sends signals and has a few slots). The project compiles fine and provides me with a nice `libwhathever.a` file

When I try to include this library in my Cascades project I get these errors when building:

> - undefined references to
>     com::vasco::digipass::sdk::utils::qrcodescanner::MyClass::staticMetaObject
> - undefined reference to
>     com::vasco::digipass::sdk::utils::qrcodescanner::MyClass::newQRCodeDetected(QString)
> - undefined reference to
>     com::vasco::digipass::sdk::utils::qrcodescanner::MyClass::staticMetaObject
>     external location:
>     c:\Developer\bbndk\target_10_1_0_2342\qnx6\usr\include\qt4\QtCore\qobject.h
> - undefined reference to
>     com::vasco::digipass::sdk::utils::qrcodescanner::MyClass::staticMetaObject
>     external location:
>     c:\Developer\bbndk\target_10_1_0_2342\qnx6\usr\include\qt4\QtDeclarative\qdeclarative.h
> - undefined reference to
>     com::vasco::digipass::sdk::utils::qrcodescanner::MyClass::staticMetaObject
>     external location:
>     c:\Developer\bbndk\target_10_1_0_2342\qnx6\usr\include\qt4\QtDeclarative\qdeclarative.h
> - undefined reference to vtable for
>     com::vasco::digipass::sdk::utils::qrcodescanner::MyClass
> - undefined
>     reference to vtable for
>     com::vasco::digipass::sdk::utils::qrcodescanner::MyClass

I suspect that I miss the compilation step where the `Q_OBJECT` macro is handled. 
Am I on the right track ?
I have heard about `moc` and `qmake` but I don't know how nor when to use them in my build process.

Answer (score 1):

Simple rule of thumb is to rerun qmake whenever you introduce a new class using `Q_OBJECT`, as it generates the `moc` files then. Try doing clean, then rerunning qmake, then building the project again and it should resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran qmake on my source and header files but for some reason it didn't generate any moc file.

I actually solved my problem simply by running moc on the header file defining the Q_OBJECT. It generated the moc file I needed and my undefined references disappeared.

Comment: QMake should be run for your project file, not sources. It would have run moc on every necessary headers.

Comment: Yes that's right, I actually made a simple .pro file before running qmake. In the end all I need for what I have is calling moc on one header, the rest of the compilation is done via an ant script